# Why does the hamburger menu get out of the wrapper block?

Tags: html, css

When the browser window is reduced, the hamburger menu crawls out of the wrapper block, but if you look in the debug menu, the hamburger does not crawl out of the block. Why is there such a difference in readings and how to make sure that in both cases the hamburger does not come out?

Code jsfiddle.net/uL05m8xw/

Site https://ct61276.tmweb.ru/

Images

https://ibb.co/rfcWY05

https://ibb.co/6H2G3jk

```css
.hamburger_wrapper {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
   .hamburger_wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    right: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
  }

}
```

```html
 <header>
        <div class="hamburger_wrapper">
            <div class="hamburger hamburger--spin">
                <div class="hamburger-box">
                    <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <h2>Frispes.</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="menu_reg_block">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Workspace</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Servics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="registration">
                    <div class="login">
                        <a href="#">Log In</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signup">
                        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Short answer is because the position is fixed. Use float: right or something else. You might want to combine the site name in the same wrapper as the header and float it left. Then there may also be an issue with the 'X' (close) button.

Comment: The main difference I can see is that when you are in debug mode the height is set to 768px, at least in the image you show which shows it is in responsive mode. There is just one of the many media settings which uses height 768. It may be worth looking at the difference between that and all the others.